# Holoedric isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

While trying to read the following article

> Schottenfells, Ida May. *Two Non-Isomorphic Simple Groups Of The Same Order 20,160*.

I found the term "holoedrically isomorphic". In an abstract for the article, I also came across the claim that "Holoedric isomorphism is the only isomorphism that can exist between two simple groups."

I haven't been able to find a definition for this term anywhere.  Presumably it is a stronger notion than that of a normal isomorphism of groups? What does it mean?

Comment: Some googling suggests it means "simply isomorphic" aka *naturally* isomorphic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isomorphism did not used to mean 1-1, just onto. Holoedric isomorphisms are both 1-1 and onto. See page 381 of Burnside's Theory of Groups (1ed).  The standard english term was "simply isomorphic", the French term was *isomorphisme holoédrique*.

The corresponding term for non-injective epimorphism (so onto, not 1-1) was "multiply isomorphic" in English, and *isomorphisme meriédrique* in French.

"édrique" appears to be about the same as "edral" as in "dihedral".

- Schottenfels, Ida May. "Two non-isomorphic simple groups of the same order 20,160."
  Ann. of Math. (2) 1 (1899/00), no. 1-4, 147–152. 
  MR[1502265](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1502265)
  DOI:[10.2307/1967281](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1967281)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.